# Difference between assigning signal inside process vs assigning actual ouput

Tags: process, vhdl, fpga, digital

So through my own study I understand that if we assign a signal inside a process, it will update after the process. Now if we directly assign an output a value will it also get updated after the process or not?
I am attaching two versions as a simple example to demonstrate what I mean.

Version 1:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity testing is
port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    a   : in std_logic;
    b   : in std_logic;
    c   : out std_logic
);

end testing;

architecture arch of testing is

signal temp: std_logic;

begin

process(clk)

begin

    if(rising_edge(clk)) then

        if(a = '1' and b = '1') then

            temp <= '1'

        end if;

    end if;

end process;

c <= temp;

end arch;
```

Now the other version:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity testing is
port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    a   : in std_logic;
    b   : in std_logic;
    c   : out std_logic
);

end testing;

architecture arch of Intermediate is

begin

process(clk)

begin

    if(rising_edge(clk)) then

        if(a = '1' and b = '1') then

            C <= '1';

        end if;

    end if;

end process;

end arch;
```

Is there a timing difference here? Will C go high sooner in the second version than compared to the first version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C` will be assigned (slightly) earlier in your second example, compared to your first. Also, less resources are used, as there is no intermediate register (temp) in your second example.

In your first example, `temp` will be assigned on the falling edge of clock, and `C` is a concurrent assignment (ie. As soon as `temp` changes, `C` changes). However, in practice this assignment happens some "small amount of time" after `temp` changes, due to signal propagation.

In your second example, you are directly assigning to `C`, which will occur on the falling clock edge.

I know the example you have provided is somewhat contrived, but you could achieve the same with:

```
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        c <= a and b;
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

First the following is not quite correct, but it is correct for most RTL processes:

> A signal inside a process does not update until after the process
>   finishes

The actual rule is:

> A signal does not update until the next delta cycle.

WRT a process, a process does not allow delta cycles to pass unless the process either suspends at a wait or exits and suspends at a sensitivity list.   Most RTL processes have either sensitivity lists or have only one wait statement at the top, hence, for RTL code we arrive at your "not quite the truth".

WRT to your assignment to C:

```
c <= temp;
```

There is still a delta cycle in that assignment.   If it helps, the language defines the execution of concurrent assignments via the following transformation:

```
process (temp) is
begin
  c <= temp;
end process ;
```

This will help you understand what is happening WRT your simple RTL rule.

Answer (score 0):

A simulation cycle resumes every process executing each until suspended by a wait. Further events for the current time cause delta cycles otherwise simulation time advances to the next scheduled event.  Simulation cycles continue until out of events or stopped.

Concurrent statements have equivalent elaborated processes or blocks and processes. An elaborated design hierarchy is a collection of processes communicating via signal events.

`c` can occur one delta cycle later in the first example because of successive signal assignments with no intervening delay. Delta cycles do not consume [simulation time](http://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~vojin/CLASSES/EEC180B/Spring99/simulation.pdf), rather produce the semblance of concurrency for sequential statements.

Version 1 has a second process from the concurrent signal assignment statement and uses an additional signal,  representing more execution time for the model and using more resources. Version 1 does not represent a significant burden by itself. Over a large number of such processes or a large number of events the difference in model execution time and memory utilization can be measurable.

Where you typically see an *intermediary signal* is where the signal value is evaluated locally in addition to driving a port. You are not allowed to read the value of an interface signal of mode out. (Design units are independently analyzed, the location of the effective value of the actual is not known at analysis time. The actual is associated at elaboration. Ports represent formals in a port association.)

See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 11. Concurrent statements 10.5.2 Simple signal assignment statements; 10.2 Wait statement; 14. Elaboration and execution; particularly 14.5 Elaboration of a statement part and 14.5.5 Other concurrent statements; 14.7 Execution of a model, particularly 14.7.5 Model execution; 6.5.2 Interface object declarations; 6.5.7.3 Port map aspects; 14.3.5 Port map aspect.